# Как записать загрузчик в первые 512 байт правильно?

Tags: linux, boot, dd

Нужно свой загрузчик (в .bin) записать в первый сектор флешки с линукса. Сначала использовал команду:

```
sudo dd if=boot.bin ibs=512 count=1 of=/dev/sdc1 obs=512 seek=1000
```

Команда

```
sudo hexdump /dev/sdc1
```

показывает, что в первые 512 байт все верно записалось (правда, с перевернутыми парами байт. Например, команда "sudo hd /dev/sdc1" показывает e9 85 00 60..., а "sudo hexdump /dev/sdc1" - 85e9 6000...)

Перезагружаю пк, жму F11, в списке выбираю "USB: ... 8GB", а BIOS выдает:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot Device or insert Boot Media in selected
>   Boot device and press a key

Понятно, что он просит. А почему просит? С "магическими" байтами все в порядке.

Comment: MBR-загрузчик должен находиться в первых 512 байт диска, а не раздела. А вы пишете в раздел, который начинается точно не с первого сектора

Comment: @andreymal а как записать именно в самое-самое начала?

Comment: И да, загрузчик занимает не 512, а 440 байт (по другим сведениям 446 байт, не уверен кому верить). Остальное занимает разметка разделов. Если вы перезапишете первые 512 байт, вы сотрёте все разделы с диска, имейте это в виду

Comment: Пишите в /dev/sdc

Comment: @andreymal записал в /dev/sdc, поменял в команде dd 512 на 440, в коде на асме убрал в конце добавление 55 aa (увидел, что во флешке изначально стоят эти байты в конце первых 512 байт) и сделал бинарник размером в 440 байт, соответственно. в меню меню выбора загрузчика появилось "UEFI: ... 8GB 8.07. Partition 1". вхожу - черный экран и меня выкидывает обратно в меню выбора загрузчика

Comment: Немного странно пытаться грузить MBR-загрузчик в UEFI

Comment: @andreymal я не особо, видимо, разбираюсь в отличиях bios от uefi, поэтому и делал все для биоса, по сути. спасибо

Comment: `seek=1000` уберите, и 512 байт будут записаны в начало, а не со смещением `512*1000` байт (`obs*seek`). но раз используется uefi, все эти манипуляции вообще не должны никак повлиять на процесс загрузки (uefi не читает первый сектор, а берёт информацию с отведённого для него раздела).